# Production vs Test proxy es6 import

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

So I'm trying to import a different javascript file based on a boolean in my react application.

When I'm running it in dev mode I want to import my testProxy.js file which just returns back json data.

When i'm running the application in production I want to use prodProxy.js where it connects to my production application via ajax and returns back results, etc.

I have achieved this with webpack by doing:

`new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
     api: isDevBuild ? "./dev/api" : "./prod/api"
}),`.

And then in my file I just declare the api.
`declare var api: any` (using typescript)

I am not really liking this and I don't know another way.

What I want is what's below

pseudo code below:

`let _api = isDev ? import('devApi') : import('prodApi');
let someObject = new MyClass(_api);`

Tried this and it fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
let _api = isDev ? import('devApi') : import('prodApi');
let someObject = new MyClass(_api);
```

this is not possibe:

**You must import all ES6 modules at the top level of your JavaScript files.**

**You can’t import an ES6 module based on a conditional.**

you can do:

```
let _api = isDev ? require('./devApi') : require('./prod/api');
let someObject = new MyClass(_api);
```

I don't know what isDev is referring to. Asuming you have some node/browser setup, and isDev is based on a environment variable passed by process.env.DEVELOPMENT, this will not be available on the client.

You would need to use the webpack evironment plugin: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/ and add the env variable to it, so u can access it from the client.

sidenote: added on build time, not on run time.

Hope this helps.